# Plugin dependency tag inside BuildConfig.groovy: how can we point to a local directory

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I have two plugin dependencies inside my build config.groovy which are

```
plugins {
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"
compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0.1"
}
```

Now due to certain proxies issues i was not able to resolve the plugins dependency through maven.
So i have downloaded the jars manually and put them inside the directory where in local any plugin gets downloaded.I want to test whether this combinations of the plugin version suits my requirement.
SO my query is Is there any way i can point to the local directory for plugin dependency resolution just to test in my local.

Comment: Grails 2 plugins are zip files, if you downloaded jars you downloaded some of the Spring Security jars that these plugins depend on

Comment: Correct.I have downloaded the zip for both of them from the url `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-core/2.0.0` & `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails.plugins/spring-security-ldap/2.0.1` and i have placed them inside the folder where the other plugins are present.But when i compile i will have to point it to the local directory where i have unzipped the zip files for the two plugins otherwise it goes again for the download and throws unable to download as it is restricted by the proxies configured in the network.

Comment: Or any other versions you can suggest which are compatible with GRAILS 2.5.1 which i can try to download through maven if the network do not block.

Comment: You should use the latest releases, not old release candidates. The versions you show in your question are the ones you should be using (2.0.0/2.0.1). Grails has support for proxies, try that so you don't need to hack in a 'solution' that's just going to cause problems later. See http://docs.grails.org/2.5.x/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html and the other proxy-related scripts

Comment: Totally Agreed.